# En esta función de Javascript el resultado en la interpolación de variables arroja NaN

Tags: javascript, condiciones, function, javascript-objeto, undefined

En este código, hay un tema de que dependiendo de la selección del usuario y por ende la selección de los ingredientes, y en donde dice por consola "de esta bebida necesitaras los siguientes ingredientes:" algunos arrojan Nan (Not a Number). Creí que era por parsear la variable volumen en una línea de instrucción aparte en vez de hacerlo directo con el prompt pero aún probando el parseo directo por prompt igual siguió arrojando NaN. Incluso pensé que era por no haber inicializado alguna variable pero en las variables a, b, c, todos sus valores de cada objeto están inicializados.

```
let user = prompt("¿Cual es tu nombre?");
let date = new Date();
let today = date.getDay();
let weekDays = [
  "domingo",
  "lunes",
  "martes",
  "miercoles",
  "jueves",
  "viernes",
  "sabado"
];
let dayName = weekDays[today];
let welcome = `Bienvenido ${user} hoy es ${dayName},`;
switch (today) {
  case today = 0:
    console.log(`${welcome} quiza no es el mejor día para beber.`);
    break;
  case today = 1:
    console.log(`${welcome} inicio de semana, ten cuidado con tu consumo.`);
    break;
  case today = 2:
    console.log(`${welcome} recupera energia, con moderación.`);
    break;
  case today = 3:
    console.log(`${welcome} ombligo de semana un par de copas ayudarán.`);
    break;
  case today = 4:
    console.log(`${welcome} ya casi es fin de semana, fuerza.`);
    break;
  case today = 5:
    console.log(`${welcome} es viernes y el cuerpo lo sabe, si tomas no conduzcas.`);
    break;
  case today = 6:
    console.log(`${welcome} se nos fue la semana, tiempo de celebrar.`);
    break;
  default:
    console.log(`${welcome} no parece un mal dia para un poco de mezcal.`);
};

let userBebida = prompt("¿Qué bebida de elixir utilizaras? (espadin o algun sabor 'Naranja, Maracuya o lichi'");
userBebida = userBebida.toLowerCase();
if (userBebida == "naranja") {
  console.log(`Solo añade hielo, algunos trozos de fruta y disfruta de tu Mezcal Elixir sabor Naranja`);
} else if (userBebida == "maracuya") {
  console.log(`Solo añade hielo, algunos trozos de fruta y disfruta de tu Mezcal Elixir sabor Maracuya`);
} else if (userBebida == "lichi") {
  console.log(`Solo añade hielo, algunos trozos de fruta y disfruta de tu Mezcal Elixir sabor Lichi`);
} else {
  console.log(`procedamos a preparar algo con tu Mezcal Espadin de Elixir`);
};

let volumen = prompt("¿Que cantidad quieres preparar?(ingresala en mililitros y solo números)");
volumen = parseInt(volumen);
volumen = volumen / 1000;

class proporcion {
  constructor(x) {
    this.agua = x.agua * volumen;
    this.mezcal = x.mezcal * volumen;
    this.jamaica = x.jamaica * volumen;
    this.tamarindo = x.tamarindo * volumen;
    this.jugo_limon = x.jugo_limon * volumen;
    this.miel = x.miel * volumen;
    this.pepino = x.pepino * volumen;
  };

  recetaNueva() {
    console.log(`para preparar ${volumen}l. de esta bebida necesitaras los siguientes ingredientes: Agua: ${this.agua}ml., Mezcal: ${this.mezcal}ml., Jamaica: ${this.jamaica}gr., Tamarindo: ${this.tamarindo}gr., Jugo de limon: ${this.jugo_limon}ml., Miel: ${this.miel} cucharadas.`);
  };
};

let a = {
  agua: 800,
  mezcal: 64,
  jugo_limon: 80,
  pepino: 2,
  miel: 5
};
//mezcalita de jamaica
let b = {
  agua: 800,
  mezcal: 64,
  jamaica: 80,
  miel: 5
};
//mezcalita de tamarindo
let c = {
  agua: 800,
  mezcal: 64,
  Tamarindo: 80,
  miel: 5
};

let receta = prompt("selecciona la receta que quieres preparar ingresando unicamente la letra de la que elijas, ejemplo, para preparar una mezcalita de 'jamaica' ingresa solo la letra 'b'");
let preparar;

switch (receta) {
  case "a":
    preparar = new proporcion(a);
    preparar.recetaNueva();
    break;
  case "b":
    preparar = new proporcion(b);
    preparar.recetaNueva();
    break;
  case "c":
    preparar = new proporcion(c);
    preparar.recetaNueva();
    break;
  default:
    console.log("ingresaste una letra que no coincide con ninguna receta");
};
volumen = volumen * 1000;

let caballitosPorServir = prompt(`tienes ${volumen} ml de esta receta ¿cuantos caballitos serviras?(solo numero)`);
console.log(caballitosPorServir);
const MILITROS_POR_CABALLITO = 30;
let mililitrosPorRonda = parseInt(caballitosPorServir) * MILITROS_POR_CABALLITO;

function calculadorRondas(bebidaDisponible) {
  for (let i = bebidaDisponible, rondaActual = 1; i > mililitrosPorRonda; i -= mililitrosPorRonda, rondaActual++) {
    let rondasRestantes = Math.trunc((i / mililitrosPorRonda) - 1);
    let salida = `Ronda ${rondaActual} serviste ${caballitosPorServir} caballitos de mezcal te quedan ${rondasRestantes} rondas`;
    if (i >= bebidaDisponible / 2) {
      console.log(`${salida} eso es mas de la mitad, la noche es joven`);
    } else if (i < bebidaDisponible / 2 && i >= bebidaDisponible / 4) {
      console.log(`${salida} queda menos de la mitad de tu bebida`);
    } else { console.log(`${salida} es momento de conseguir mas Elixir`); }
  };
};
calculadorRondas(volumen);







<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Calculadora de recetas de bebidas</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: En el objeto para la receta `c` escribiste `Tamarindo` con `t` mayúscula y deberia ser en minúscula. Todas las recetas deberían tener TODOS los mismos ingredientes y en cero si no lo necesitan o deberías validar su existencia en el constructor de `proporcion`

Comment: Veo que estás usando mal el switch... debería ser solo `case 0:` en vez de case `today = 0:`